# Call input inside quotation (TA addline in quantmod)

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I had a problem to call the input in `TA` option from `chartSeries` in `quantmod` package on R Shiny.

Here's the code

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart", click = "SD1")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  df <- reactive(getSymbols("JPM", src = "google", auto.assign = F))
  output$chart <- renderPlot(
    chartSeries(
      df(),
      type = "candlesticks",
      TA = "addLines(v = input$SD1$x, on = 1)"
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Returns `object 'input' not found`

Comment: What do you want to do with `TA`? Your error comes from there. You pass `input$SD1$x` and it doesn't know what you're trying to get.

Comment: `addLines` here is used to add a vertical line while `input$SD1$x` is the x axis value of your mouse click

Comment: you are aware that input$SD1$x is numeric, while your x-axe is of type date? So you want to convert the input into a date?

Comment: @BigDataScientist I don't think it's this issue cause if I put `addLines` outside the function it will work. I think the problem is R cannot find `input$SD1$x` inside the quotation marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason this works:

```
data <- getSymbols("JPM", src = "google", auto.assign = F)
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart", click = "SD1")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  global <- reactiveValues(v = NULL)

  observe({
    v <- input$SD1$x / 3
    if(!is.null(v) & length(v)) global$v <- v
  })

  output$chart <- renderPlot(
    chartSeries(
      data,
      type = "candlesticks",
      TA = paste0("addLines(v = ", global$v, ", on = 1)")
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you it works! Sorry I cannot give 2 correct answers. His one is easier to understand. But thank you all the same!

Comment: Does the other answer work for you? For me it updates and the line immediately vanishes again ?

Comment: Yep, actually I know how to keep the line, just want to simplify the question so I posted the above code. But I'm very thankful to your answer as well as the addition feature.

Comment: Sorry I should give the right answer to you. His one forgot the `type = "candlestick"` and won't work if I add this argument.

Comment: Hey, could you please explain why you divided by 3? It seems the index for different charts are different. If we switch to type = "line" then we cannot observe the vertical line unless we remove the `/3` any ideas? and for `type = "bars"` it didn't work properly with or without `/3`

Comment: For `line` and `matchsticks`, we just remove the `/3`. For `bars`, we should `/4`

Comment: It fails to work when we only have small amount of data.

Comment: Finally I got some weird solution, please see: https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/190

Answer (score 1):

First extract click `x <- input$SD1$x` and then `paste0` `addLine` command.

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("chart", click = "SD1")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  df <- reactive({getSymbols("JPM", src = "google", auto.assign = F)})
  output$chart <- renderPlot({
    # Extract click
    x <- input$SD1$x
    # Create addline command 
    addLineCmd <- paste0("addLines(v = ", x, ", on = 1)")
    chartSeries(
      df(),
      TA = addLineCmd
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Arthur Everything that's passed with `input$SD1$x` is a string (in our case it's some number). We collapse that number with command. Let's say number (`x`) is 5. Then we collapse using `paste0`: `commandA 5 commandB`. Before you passed: `commandA input$SD1$x commandB`. Before you had: `addLines(v = input$SD1$x, on = 1)` now you have `addLines(v = 5, on = 1)`